# Comments section not forming in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, comments

My comments section is not forming in Laravel. I get "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.", but I do not have POST method anywhere in my web.php. This is it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BlogController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController;

Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'index'])->name('index');

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource('/blogs', [BlogController::class, 'index'])->name('blogs');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/article', [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'index'])->name('article');

Route::get('/create', [App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('create');

Route::get('/blogs/{id}', [CommentsController::class, 'index'])->name('blogs');
Route::get('/blogs/{id}', [CommentsController::class, 'store'])->name('blogs');
```

Comment: You have a form attempting to submit via POST, but you do not have any POST routes except what is created by `Route::resource('/blogs'` and `Auth::routes()`. Double-check the route that the comment form is using

Comment: I had some POST methods in the code, like ``` <form action="{{ route('blogs.destroy',$blog->id) }}" method="POST"> ``` but I replaced it with GET. The comments section is formed and I can make a comment, but it brings me back to blogs/{id}. The comment is stored, apparently, because I do get an extension to the link with the author and text info, but it is not stored in my database.

Comment: `blogs.destroy` would be either a POST or DELETE method, not GET. GET is more for retrieving data, not sending data. On your command line in your project directory, do `php artisan routes:list` to see all of the routes you have defined with the methods they support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "PUT","PATCH","HEAD" or "DELETE" method you need to specify the method in your form like this :

```
<form method="POST">
@method('delete')
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `\storage\framework\views\145ba5a124cf3e653f6b59e6acf30206719d86de.php` file. Just had to modify the method. Hopefully this is useful.